# Making full year schedule of event using php date function

Tags: php, date

I have an event having the following properties:

```
id
name
weekday
```

So, an event happens every week on that weekday. I wanted to create an array containing all the dates (Format: dd-mm-yyyy), when that event will take place two specific dates.

I'm unable to figure out the appropriate logic/code.

I implemented the following code:

```
$day = date('d');//returns today's date in 2-digit format.
$year = date('Y');//4-digit format of current year
$month = date('m');//2-digit format of current month
$cal = array();
$ttdayid = $weekday;//5
$tt = 0;
$tt = abs($day-$ttdayid);
$ttday = $date - $tt;
while ($ttday>0) {
    if ($ttday<10) {
        $ttday = '0' . $ttday;
    }
    $arr = array(
                'id'    => $id,  
                'title' => $name,
                'start' => $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $ttday
                    );
    array_push($cal, $arr);
    $ttday-= 7;
}
```

The above code works for the current month only before today. I'm unable to figure out how to extend it to show dates for previous and next months for the whole year. Also, how to included cases for leap years.

Comment: Look into using [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). It makes doing this a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `DateTime()` object:

```
$current = new DateTime(); // creates a date for "today" by default
$end = new DateTime('yyyy-mm-dd'); // the ending date
$interval = new DateInterval('P7D'); // 1 week


while($current <= $end) {
    $cal[] = $current->format('Y-m-d');
    $current = $current->add($interval);
}
```